# Can I earn Frequent Flier miles on a flight using FF miles and effectively get them back?

Tags: credit-card, airline, frequent-flier-miles

Let us say I have accumulated 50,000 air miles and use it on a flight on Alaska Air from Vancouver  to Anchorage. Now , is it correct that just by taking the flight itself, I will earn back 'all' those 50 000 miles. It seems like the flight is free in that case.

Comment: This question might be better on [travel.SE](http://travel.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flight from Vancouver to Anchorage is approximately 1571 miles. Alaskan Airlines may  charge you 50,000 miles to book a flight but you only earn back 1 mile for every 1 mile you fly. So in face it may take you 50,000 miles in flying in order to earn 50,000 miles or by opening a new credit card with Alaska Air.

It is a marketing scheme where you earn miles by opening a credit card and use it to book flights or joining their frequent flyer program.

Hope you check and understand difference between air miles earn and use policy.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You don't earn FF miles when flying on an award ticket on any airline that I'm aware of.